# How to stop a dropdown menu from flowing into the bottom bar?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I have an Android Activity in my app that's a form inside of a ScrollView. At the very bottom of the form is a Spinner set to drop down. I'm trying to have the currently selected item stay where it is when the Spinner drop down is opened (as per Material specs), but when an item from near the top of the menu is selected, the drop down selector flows into the bottom bar:

[image: Drop down menu flowing into bottom bar]

How are you supposed to deal with this? Do you make the Activity height larger? Do you cut the drop down list off and put in a scroll bar? Do you just shift the whole list up so that it isn't overlaying the bottom bar?

On a related note, when I select the first item in the list, the vertical offset isn't correctly set, but it is when I select the second or third item:

```
            spinInvestment.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @TargetApi(16)
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                int offset = 6 +
                        (spinInvestment.getSelectedItemPosition() - 2) * 60;
                Log.d(TAG, "Spinner offset = " + offset);
                spinInvestment.setDropDownVerticalOffset(offset);
                return false;
            }
```

I can't think of any reason why selecting that first choice (which would set the offset to -114) wouldn't correctly move the drop down to where it should be. It isn't like negative offsets aren't allowed - selecting the second choice would correctly produce a -54 offset.

Comment: seems like a bug to me